# Material assign not lining up with vertices

Tags: materials

[image]
Hi Guys,
Can somebody explain to me why, when assigning a material to specific vertices, it doesn't seem to line up. Am I doing something wrong or is it supposed to be like this? Thanks!

Comment: Your subdivision surface modifier repositions the vertices. Add a supporting edge loop just below and above the material transition.

Comment: Thanks guys! That does it for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have subdivision modifier on your mesh.Which lowers the resulting vertices when it smooths the mesh.Try assigning after applying the subdivision modifier.